# lift map projective point

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, projective-space

I remember there is a theorem in algebraic geometry that, if $f: X-P\rightarrow Y$ is a morphism, then it can be lifted to a map $\tilde{f}: X\rightarrow Y$.  It required I believe $X$ and $Y$ to be projective, though.  Where is that theorem found, so I can look to see what exact conditions are necessary.

Comment: You want $X$ to be a smooth curve and $Y$ to be projective. See the first chapter of Hartshorne.

Comment: The easiest situation to think about is when $X$ is a Riemann surface. The analytic ideas are more or less as the algebraic ideas in Hartshorne. I can elaborate if you want.

Comment: Here is the closest that I found in Hartshorne: `Let Y be a variety of dimension >=2, P in Y normal point, f regular function on Y-P.  Then f extends to a regular function on Y`  Is this what you were referring to?

Comment: Hartshorne, Chapter 1, Prop 6.8, page 43.

Comment: OK, thanks!  I just found it too.  Would you like to post this as an answer?